# Remove milliseconds in a datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime, substring

I converted a database from MS SQL to MySql using workbench. There is a table that has a column called `ActivityDate` (`datetime(6)`) . For some reason, when that column got converted it has a dot in the date like (`2013-05-03 11:20:20.420000`) .

I want to remove the .420000 or whatever number is after the dot. I tried doing `SUBSTRING_INDEX(ActivityDate,'.',1)` but that didn't work, the last digits would just be `.000000`

I also tried `UPDATE`alerts`.`activitylog`SET`ActivityDate`= date_format(ActivityDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')  WHERE`activitylog`.`ActivityLogID`= 5;`

And same issue... I get `.000000` at the end

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that the data type of the column is `DATETIME` and not `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it says datetime(6)

Comment: The reason is, of course, that both SQL Server and MySQL support fractional seconds. (Though you need MySQL/5.6.4 or greater, which you most likely don't have.) –

Comment: try `select microsecond( time_column )`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply change the data type of the column to exclude the fractional part.

```
ALTER TABLE alerts.activitylog MODIFY ActivityDate DATETIME;
```

The type *`datetime(6)`* means *`6 digits after the decimal point`*.

See the [MySQL date and time fractional support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select the datetime without the ms (like I was when I found this question) then the below `CAST` does the job:

```sql
SELECT CAST(created_at AS DATETIME) AS created_at_without_ms
```

Comment: this rounds the date time and does not trunc the ms

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove the milliseconds as part of a SELECT rather than changing the data in the table, you can do:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at), 0))
```

This avoids the rounding performed by CAST as mentioned in the previous answer.